# Using guava in griffon gives Prohibited package exception

Tags: guava, griffon

I am using Griffon and want to add the guava libraries as a dependency in my project. However, when I do this, even without using 1 class of it, I get the following exception:

```
Compilation error: BUG! exception in phase 'canonicalization' in source unit
'/home/wdb/myproject/griffon-app/controllers/MyController.groovy' Prohibited
package name: java.util.concurrent
```

Any idea what might be wrong? This is my java version (on Ubuntu 11.10):

```
wdb@wdb-laptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
```

I found [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/java-forkjoin-parallel-programming.html) that talks about using the bootclasspath for a similar problem, but that seems a bit drastic.

regards,

Wim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be that Griffon does not honor 'provided' scope. I managed to get it working by editing `BuilderConfig.groovy` to:

```
compile( 'com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1' ) { 
    exclude 'guava-bootstrap' 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My wild guess is that our [bootclasspath copy of java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/#git/guava-bootstrap/src/java/util/concurrent) (necessary due to an incompatible change between JDK5 and JDK6) is showing up in your classpath.  I don't really know Maven, but I would think that, because [we identify the dependency as "provided"](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/pom.xml#30), this [shouldn't be happening](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

That's not really an answer, but I hope it's enough to get you or someone else started.